# Letsencrypt / certbot "could not be properly decoded in UTF-8" warning message when issuing a certificate

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi2, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a `Raspberry Pi webserver` on which i have installed `certbot` to use ssl.
Since a few days the renew function has a warning in it.

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:1869: UserWarning: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twython-3.4.0.egg-info could not be properly decoded in UTF-8
  warnings.warn(msg)
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
```

It looks like the certs are getting created fine but I still would like to know how to get rid off this warning.

I am using `python3` with `certbot 0.28.0`

Does someone know how to solve my warning?

‐-------------- UPDATE ----------------

Apperently the file twython-3.4.0.egg-info has nothing to do and is not used with certbot... as far as it seems it got installed with an update from my system orso. As I have read it is a file for doing stuff with twitter.... nothing I use or need. So I have moved this file to another directory with this my warning went away.

As far as I can imagine there probably is a character that doesnot get parsed the right way and was not detected by the verifier I used to check if the file was actually utf-8 decodeable.

Comment: [github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/4958](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/4958#issuecomment-325131084)

Comment: Ruturaj Thank you for your fast reply. I also came across this. However this is another file made by another author. So I have not been able to find such same bug in it.

Comment: You really should rather notify Certbot authors about this issue.

Comment: So I found out it's not certbot related. I have just run pip3 --version which gave me the exact same warning before the version was shown.